# verifying a predicate in dafny is true for all integers

Tags: dafny

I am fairly new to dafny and I am trying to verify that every integer is either even or odd. I have the code below:

```
method Main() {
  
  Test();
  
  
}


predicate Test (a : int)

{
  
  assert (forall a :: a % 2 == 0 || a % 2 != 0);
  
  
}
```

But dafny is complaining that my predicate is wrong and I am not sure why. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi, was there an error message?

Comment: yes, Dafny 2.3.0.10506
stdin.dfy(16,0): Error: invalid LogicalExpression
1 parse errors detected in stdin.dfy

Answer (score 0):

A `predicate` is different from a `method` in that the body of a `predicate` must be an expression. For example, if you delete the `assert` keyword and the semicolon at the end of that line, then it will parse correctly.

Additionally, there are a few other issues here. First, it looks like `Test` is declared to take a parameter `a`, but the call from `Main` does not pass a value for this parameter. Did you mean for `Test` not to take any parameters? Second, in order to call a `predicate` from a `method`, you must declare the `predicate` as a `predicate method`, which is just like a `predicate` except it can be called from `method`s.

Comment: Hi James, thanks for your feedback. I am trying to verify, in dafny, that every integer is either odd or even, so I don't want to pass an integer as an argument, but rather, show, somehow, that all integers do indeed obey this property.

Comment: I am not sure how I would do this

Comment: method Main (x : int) {
  
   assert (x % 2 == 0 || x % 2 == 1);
  
}

Comment: sounds like you figured it out!

Comment: another way to do it would be:
method Main() {
  assert (forall x :: x % 2 == 0 || x % 2 == 1);
}